# Преобразование к типу date

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть скрипт в MS SQL

```
select dt_date,
  CONVERT(date,
    CONCAT(
      SUBSTRING(replace(dt_bad_string,' year ','-'),0,6),
      SUBSTRING(replace(dt_bad_string,' month ','-'),11,2),
      SUBSTRING(replace(dt_bad_string,' day ',''),19,2) 
    )
  )
from skill_events
```

для преобразования строки вида
`2020 year 8 month 9 day`
в тип date
2020-08-09

Сборка проходит без ошибки - получается вид 2020-8-9
При конвертации в date выдает ошибку

> Msg 241 Level 16 State 1 Line 1
> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Answer (score 0):

Я бы так сделал, вдруг пробелов может стать больше. Минуя substring и concat

```
DECLARE @dt_bad_string VARCHAR(255) = '2020 year 8 month 9 day'

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(DATETIME, REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@dt_bad_string, 'year', '-'), 'month', '-'), 'day', ''), ' ', '')), 23)
```

Это тоже работает

```
DECLARE @dt_bad_string VARCHAR(255) = '2020 year 8 month 9 day'

SELECT CONVERT(DATE, REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@dt_bad_string, 'year', '-'), 'month', '-'), 'day', ''), ' ', ''))
```